# HTTP access control (CORS) purpose

Tags: web-browser, cors

As there is an option to disable HTTP access control (CORS) in browsers, so I can send requests to any origin. So why should I bother to run a Browser with CORS enabled?

Comment: It's mainly to protect copyright owners against deeplinking and client-side scraping.

Comment: A modern web application typically has frontend code and a backend API. The frontend code is static HTML, Javascript and CSS. You could just copy that static code and host it under a different domain, and still use the same backend API. CORS prevents that.

Comment: What does that have do with anything the question says?

Comment: If sites can be spoofed, it's in the user's best interest to have CORS enabled.

Comment: Ok, but the sites are separated from eachother, i.e. the Javascript of a malicious site can't affect another. Except some very tricky things, like posting forms.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**For your own good.**

If you disable CORS the following can happen:

I send you link to a page called `hackfacebook.com` for example. When you visit my page, I then request the facebook.com page using an AJAX request which if you are logged in returns the page content as well as your session cookie.

I now as the owner of `hackfacebook.com` have your login session.

As you can see disabling CORS is at your own risk as it can open up another attack.

Comment: I though that it is for protecting serve resources ... like REST apis

Comment: can one read cookies cross-domain like that?

Comment: @dandavis If you have disabled the SOP by allowing cross domain requests without CORS, then yes you can. Just read the response headers.

Comment: @Anders: i figured "disabling CORS" != "disabling SOP", so i would expect fewer "perms", not more...

Comment: @dandavis Yeah, the wording is a bit vague here. I would take "disable CORS" to mean "disable the requirement to get permission via CORS before giving access to the contents of cross domain requests".

Comment: So the only way for `hackfacebook.com` can get ahold of facebook's session cookie is if the user disabled SOP?

Comment: If I am right then the answer is partly incorrect: disabling CORS does not mean that you can steal the session cookie for another site. You cannot access the header containing the cookie with JS just because I turn of CORS, or do you? But thanks for the answer, it is obvious for me now that you can steal my Facebook username, etc.

Comment: ok, so if I set up hackfacebook.com to use a proxy api and forge the request to facebook, I would still be able to do what you just described. CORS doesn't solve any real security threat.

Comment: @user2167582 the difference is you won't be logged in as the user when you make a Facebook request, so malicious scripts can't use your session to take privileged action on some third party site (like posting that "you're coming out of the closet" on your feed.)

Comment: Are you telling me that the browser will let the JS script of another domain and tab to access the cookies set by another tab and domain if CORS aren't correctly configured ?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of CORS is to prevent a web browser that respects it from calling the server using non-standard requests with content served from a different location.

Standard requests are basically

- GET
- HEAD
- POST (but only certain types like `application/x-www-urlencoded`, i.e. not `application/json`)

With just the limited set of standard headers.  Anything outside those constraints will trigger a CORS check via an `OPTIONS` call.

Comment: you only describe the preflight check, you don't really answer the question.